# Getting Started with MapBasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

I am new to MapBasic.

I googled for tutorials and found various PDFs but could not get started with the resources.

I would be glad if anyone could provide some path for learning MapBasic.

Comment: Hello everyone I need som help.How could I æa rectengular and a line useing mapbasic window in mapinfo .Could you share nessesary codes:/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was lucky enough to learn MapBasic from some other colleagues.
I have not found many resources for MapBasic other than what Precisely offers on the [site](https://support.precisely.com/products/mapinfo-mapbasic/).
I spotted [this tutorial](http://www.tydac.ch/de/pdf/mapbasic.pdf) that looks fairly good for new starters.

- [Online Forum](https://community.precisely.com/home)
- [Knowledge Base](https://customer.precisely.com/s/topic/0TO6g0000005GIPGA2/mapbasic?language=en_US)
- [MapBasic Product Documentation](https://support.precisely.com/products/mapinfo-mapbasic/)  [v2021 link.](https://docs.precisely.com/docs/sftw/mapinfo-mapbasic/v2021/en-us/pdf/mapinfo-pro-2021-mapbasic-reference.pdf)

There is currently only a handful of MapBasic questions on this site, and only a few people are following that tag, but if you have more specific questions, feel free to ask here and we will try and help out.

Comment: I would add the MapInfo-L google group to that list for help: http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l/topics

Comment: Yes, good point, I subscribe to that and its helped me a lot with MapBasic Qs

Comment: The tutorial with the link is incomplete :(

Comment: Still works for me.  This 1 right:  
http://www.tydac.ch/de/pdf/mapbasic.pdf

Comment: yea the tutorial link works but it's pages are stripped off. :(

Answer (score 13):

Also if you are looking for a way to learn MapBasic more than a way to learn to program, there is a huge help in MapInfo Pro thru the MapBasic window.

Open the MapBasic window (Options > Show MapBasic Window) and do the task you want to code in MapBasic in MapInfo Pro. MapInfo Pro will now write the MapBasic statements required. You can now copy these into your MapBasic source code and work from this.

It's not all that can be done this way, but it gives you a very good insight into a lot of the MapBasic statements

There are also a number of web pages where you can find tools including MapBasic source code to get you on the right track.

Sometimes it might be helpful to have a look at the source code for an existing tool to see how it has been made.

Have a look at these sites:

- [MapInfo Marketplace](http://mapinfomarketplace.precisely.com/)
- http://georezo.net/jparis/
- http://www.jpsservices.org.uk/blog/category/mapbasic
- [TWIAV - MapBasic Tips & Tricks](https://twiav.nl/php/mapbasic.php)
- [The MapInfo Pro Developer Group on Precisely Knowledge Communities](https://community.precisely.com/communities/community-home?CommunityKey=3c2aca7a-c3ae-4602-a142-9ee956769d55)
- (http://mapinfotools.com/) This is not working properly anymore
- (http://www.directionsmag.com/files/) This has been taken down
- (http://communitydownloads.pbinsight.com/) has been replaced by the MapInfo marketplace

Some of these sites do hold some pretty old tools but many of these will still work.

You can also find some other discussion forums where you can find answers and ask your own:

- [The MapInfo Pro Community on Precisely Knowledge Communities](https://community.precisely.com/communities/community-home?communitykey=fe4d1ee2-f1c6-4307-87d2-00bea1344885)
- [The MapInfo-L on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mapinfo-l)

As for actual writing MapBasic application, I will only recommend the MapBasic Text Editor for small projects. As soon as you start creating more advanced projects I would recommend that you find a better text editor.

One option here would be to use the [MapBasic IDE](https://mustafaozcetin.wordpress.com/mapbasic/mapbasicide-en/) developed by Mustafa ÖZÇETİN. On the blog, you can find a very good guide to getting started with the MapBasic IDE.

Answer (score 4):

Not a tutorial but something I found very useful is this site: http://www.twiav.nl/php/mapbasic.php

I would highly recommend setting up Notepad++ (or something similar). Syntax highlighting, bulk indenting and bulk commenting can speed things up massively.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for digging out an old thread, but the **MapBasic UserGuide** and **MapBasic Reference** are probably the 2 best resources for getting started with MapBasic.

I myself started off simply observing code generation in the MapBasic Window (see what Peter suggested). Then I started making my own MapBasic Window scripts in Excel:

[image: Excel Script Example]

Then after a while I found out that MapBasic can be compiled into .MBX tools and these have the benefit of being able to use Loops, Flow control, dialogues etc.

So then I started writing .mb files and compiling them to .MBX. After a little while longer I started wanting to make MapBasic applications with Ribbon Buttons. You can do this with the Alter ButtonPad statement but it is better to use the RIBBONLib created by Peter. To do so you need to get started with .MBPs - I found this difficult but got their in the end.

As you can see from my own experience, I've learnt more as and when I wanted it and have always strove to develop my knowledge. This has involved lots of googling, lots of reading in the MapBasic reference/userguide, lots of talking to PBSupport and lots of reading from (and asking questions on) MapInfo-L google group.